# Set view controller as the first controller in UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have this code in my appDelegate.m that implements a UINavigationController with a UITabBarController:

```
FristViewController *primeiro = [[FristViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav1 pushViewController:primeiro animated:YES];

    FilesViewController *segundo = [[FilesViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav2 pushViewController:segundo animated:YES];

    InfoViewController *terceiro = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav3 pushViewController:terceiro animated:YES];

    UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav2, nav1, nav3, nil];
    nav1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1.png"];
    nav2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2.png"];
    nav3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3.png"];

    self.window.rootViewController = tab bar;
```

It's all right with this code, in my case when I beginning my app appearing on the first controller is FilesViewController because it is the first in the order of Tab Bar, but in my case I would like the first controller was the FristViewController without changing the order of items in the tab bar, how can I do this?

Comment: Very confusingly written question, anyway: tabbar.selectedIndex = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Go to your storyboard or xib where you created your TabBar. Drag the First controller to 1st position. Or programmatically you could set tabBar.selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Almost, but the 1) OP says he/she doesn't want to reorder the tabs 2) the tab bar not created in xib, 3) selected index is 0 by default, 4) the OP, very confusingly, says he/she wants the middle tab of three selected which means selectedIndex = 1; 5) tabBar has no uppercase B in the OP